# Supress blank space between detail section and page footer in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report like this:
[image]

Page Footer b is just shown in last page;

And the generated report is like this:

[image]

Can I supress the blank space between detail section and report footer?
I need the report footer a in all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Footer Section/Subsection will always print at the bottom of the page. As an alternative you can

1. Add/copy the contents of the Page Footer Section/Subsection to the Report Footer Section also.
2. Suppress the Page Footer Section/Subsection on the last page using the formula
   `PageNumber=TotalPageCount`

It will print Page Footer on all other pages but not on last page. Contents of report footer will print at the end of the report, including your copied page footer content. But keep in mind that you have multiple Page Footer Sub-sections, you may need to apply the formula and format your report accordingly. Additionally care needs to be taken if your have formula, calculations in the page footer.

Along with above setting, if you want to hide vertical lines too, then you will have to draw the lines in two parts.

1. From Report Header Section to Report Footer Section.
2. For Page Footer Sections draw separate lines from first Page Footer to last page footer.

For formatting purpose you may also need to enable `Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing` option in `Format Line`